# Determining whether a given latitude and longitude is on land or ocean with C# by using any formula

Tags: c#, latitude-longitude

Can you please let us know following

Determining whether a given latitude and longitude is on land or ocean with C# by using any formula?

We don't want to use any online service

Comment: I hate to break it to you but the Earth's geography hasn't been formed via a formula. Also, there are parts of the planet where the answer depends on the time (i.e. tidal areas)

Comment: I wish life was this simple